C# ServiceBusTrigger dynamic topicName, subscriptionName
I am doing a migration to .net8 isolated process
I have a small issue, i'm guessing it was answered or asked in some other places but can't really find it.
I have my local.settings.json that look something like this .
"TopicName": "dev",
"SubscriptionName": "dev",

In my Program.cs, in case there is a Debugger Attached, i'm trying to modify them.
configuration["TopicName"] = Environment.MachineName;
configuration["SubscriptionName"] = Environment.MachineName;

The method looks something like this.
public async Task HandleResponse([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "connString")] byte[] message, [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client)

It's not binding the new value.
I'm guessing this solution will not work, correct?
If so, is it even possible to somehow do it?
I can't pass Configuration as a param
